# Conversion c# lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, select, where-clause

How to convert this request res to res2?
I want to browse objects twice from a query.

```
var res = (from t1 in lst
           from t2 in lst
           select new { t1, t2 }).ToList();

var res2 = lst.Select(t1=> x)
           lst.Select(t2x=> x)
           .......
```

I want to get the same result as the res1 request in the res2 request but by using the **.Select(** function. I do not know how to write res2

link to **"Select"** function : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
var query =
    fruits.Select((fruit, index) =>
                  new { index, str = fruit.Substring(0, index) });
```

I want to use the same writing as the microsoft example for the request "res2" but by including 2 times the list "lst".

How to do it more than 2 times, for example 3, 4, ... thanks

```
var res2 = lst.SelectMany(x => lst, (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 }).ToList();

var res = (from t1 in lst
           from t2 in lst
           from t3 in lst
           from t4 in lst
           select new { t1, t2, t3, t4 }).ToList();
```

Comment: Won't this code (`from t1 in lst from t2 in lst select new { t1, t2 }`) do a cross join of `lst` on itself (i.e., if you have 10 members in the list, you will get 100 new items created in your output list).  Is that what you want?

Comment: Please include sample data and expected output.

Comment: I want to compare each object t1 of lst with each object t2 of lst. Then get an object list t1 corresponding to my Where query.

Comment: Thank you all for the speed and the answers.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross join LINQ

```
var res2 = lst.SelectMany(x => lst, (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 });
```

Comment: How to do it more than 2 times, for example 3, 4, ... thanks? t3, t4, ...

Comment: @Axel this is cross join or known as Cartesian join.

Comment: i found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930508/selectmany-applied-to-3-lists
    `var res3 = lst.SelectMany(
                t1 => lst.SelectMany(
                    t2 => lst.Select(
                        t3 => new {
                            t1,
                            t2,
                            t3
                  }))
              ).ToList();`

Comment: Thank you all for the speed and the answers. :)